# Dynamic field in graphql object type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have some GraphQL types:

```
const Atype = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Atype',
  fields: {
    data: { type: ADataType },
    error: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})
```

and

```
const Btype = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Btype',
  fields: {
    data: { type: BDataType },
    error: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})
```

It looks redundant because only `data` fields are different...

How can I solve it in more elegant way in GraphQL ?

Comment: I don't know this way is redundant or not for you, but I can say this way is elegant. Take a look http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a new **Type** named **Mixed** just to solve similar issue., Mixed works as mongoose Mixed type, If you're familiar with it.

Create a new file named `GraphQLMixed.js` or name it whatever you want and place this code inside it.

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

const GraphQLMixed = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Mixed',
  serialize: value => value,
  parseValue: value => value,
  parseLiteral: ast => ast.value
});

export default GraphQLMixed;
```

Now, Based on your syntax I assume you're using **express-graphql**, So wherever you want to use this type, Do this

```
const GraphQLMixed = require('path/to/file/GraphQLMixed');

const Atype = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Atype',
  fields: {
    data: { type: GraphQLMixed },
    error: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})

const Btype = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Btype',
  fields: {
    data: { type: GraphQLMixed },
    error: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})
```

Hope this works and helps.

Comment: Hi @random-user, it's mean whatever data structure serve to fields `data`, it can be handle right ?